# Owin WebApp Dispose does not release URL Registration

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using SignalR in a .Net Windows service (using Microsoft.Owin v4.0.1.0). Due to the requirements of the application, I need to be able to stop and later restart the SignalRHub. The code I doing this with is

```
HubWebApp = WebApp.Start(HubURL)
```

Then later:

```
HubWebApp.Dispose()
```

Then later still:

```
HubWebApp = WebApp.Start(HubURL)
```

The problem is that when I start the WebApp for the 2nd time after earlier disposing of it to stop the SignaRHub, I'm getting the error:

> "Failed to listen on prefix 'http://172.16.4.55:8080/' because it
>   conflicts with an existing registration on the machine".

So it looks like it's not releasing the URL registration when I dispose the WebApp, and refusing a new listener on this same URL when I restart it.

I tried messing around with netsh http, but delete doesn't work and show doesn't show the existing registration.

How can I release the URL registration when I dispose the WebApp?

Comment: I have a test application that I can start and stop SignalR hub several times which does not throw such an exception. Did you debug and see that Dispose line really hits?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am certain that the HubWebApp.Dispose() line executed - it's in a StopHub() method where the last line writes out to a log file so I know all the code in the mehod executed. Thanks though, it was a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Never found solution to unregister the URL. What I wound up doing is coding the service to exit with an error if restarting the hub throws an exception (Environment.Exit(1)). Then configure the service in Service Manager to automatically restart if it exits with an error.

This is a real Wear A Paper Bag Over Your Head kludge, but it's the best answer I've got for now.